The emulator process for AVD Pixel_3a_API_30 has terminated
i just ugraded to windows 11 and after the upgrade i downloded Android Studio the new version (Koala feature Drope) and jdk and made my android sdk to the D: .. and still faces problem that the Emulator has terminated ( however the emulator worked on win10 )  .. i tried to Cold boot , Wipe data and delete it and download the emulator again and still
When i searched for it i knew that if i click on ( Help -> Show Log on Explorer -> idea.txt
then i may find the reason of the problem and i searched for Pixel by (CTRL + F) to see what is the problem and didn't understand ..
So please help :) .. Thanks
i expected to the emulator run and didnt
